# What is the proper phrasing of this logical statement?

Tags: logic

Let $P$ be the statement "Every multiple of 6 is even and is not a multiple of 4."

(a)Rewrite $P$ in the form "for all..., if ..., then ... ." Use variables.

(b)Write the negation of $P$.

For (a) I have:

For all integers $n$, if $n=6k$ for some integer $k$, then $n$ is even and is not a multiple of $4$. I have then written the statement in the following form: $$ P: \forall n \in \{ \mathbb{Z} \mid n=6k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \}, (\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n=2k) \land (\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, n \neq 4k)$$

So from there, I have attempted to negate P:
$$ \neg P: \exists n \in \{ \mathbb{Z}\mid n=6k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \}, (\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, n \neq 2k) \lor (\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n=4k)$$

The point of the exercise is to express the negation in sentence form, however. What I have written is "There is some integer $n$, such that $n=6k$, where $n$ is not even, or $n$ is a multiple of four.

Is there a better way to express either of these statements? I am most concerned with the way I have turned the negation back into sentence form, it doesn't seem to flow to me and I would like to know if it is correct.

Comment: You haven’t expressed “$n$ is even and is not a multiple of $4$” correctly. You expressed this as $n=2k \land n \neq 4k$, but in what you wrote, what is $k$? One way to express “$n$ is even” is $\exists k\in\mathbb Z \mbox{ s.t. } n=2k$. Does that help you get further?

Comment: Also, it’s safest to start negations by writing “It is not the case that...” So here, “It is not the case that for all integers $n$,...”, which becomes “There exists an integer $n$ such that it is not the case that if $n$ is a multiple of $6$, then (both) $n$ is even and $n$ is not a multiple of $4$”.

Comment: @SteveKass I have edited the forms of my statements. Hopefully they work better. I don't feel that your alternative sentence helps though. The negation of a conjunction is a disjunction by definition so I really don't think it makes my sentence sound better to write "it isn't the case that both of these are true" when the negation distributes fine.

Comment: I didn’t mean for my last sentence to be the answer - you still have to keep going (and change $\land$ to $\lor$, as you did). It’s just that it can be safer to proceed one step at a time using “It is not the case that...” initially for each negation. Also, your final attempt at sentence form again raises the question “what is $k$?”. Better to start the final answer, I think, as “There is at least one multiple of $6$ that is...” And in English, “odd” is usually the way to say “not even.”

Comment: The negation is: $\lnot \forall n \ [(\exists k \ (n= 6 \times k)  \to ( \exists j \ (n= 2 \times j)  \land \forall z \lnot (n=4 \times z))]$.

Comment: It is equiv to: $∃n [∃k (n=6×k) ∧ (¬∃j (n=2×j) \lor ∃z(n=4×z))]$.